# Preventing ActiveRecord migration from making huge changes in db/structure.sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

When running the ActiveRecord migration below on the test (**not** production) database, large changes in `db/structure.sql` appear. This is reproducible. The changes are:

- A small number of the expected changes based on the migration code (as desired).
- A large number of unexpected changes, which are unrelated to the migration code (not desired). **All these unexpected changes rearrange the order of the tables, views and materialized views** that are **not** mentioned in the SQL code in the migration. These rearranged tables, views and materialized views are **not** associated (e.g., by dependencies) with the items in the SQL code in the migration.

## What causes these large unrelated differences, and, *most importantly, how to prevent these large unrelated differences*?

Could they be related to the mismatch between the postgresql versions on the production database server and on the machine where the migrations are executed on the test database?

These unrelated changes make `git diff` output **much** less useful. Same goes for `diff` results on GitHub.

In this tiny minimal example below, just a few tables are rearranged. But in the real life (larger) migration it changes the order of dozens of tables, views and matviews - a **huge change**.

```ruby
class FixFooBarBaz < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def up
    sql = <<~SQL
                  DROP VIEW master_foo;
                  DROP VIEW IF EXISTS bar1;
                  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bar1 AS
                  SELECT * FROM baz1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT * FROM baz2;
                  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW master_foo AS
                  SELECT
                      *,
                      'bar1' AS bar_type
                  FROM
                      bar1
                  UNION ALL
                  ...
    SQL

    execute sql
  end

  def down
    sql = <<~SQL
                  DROP VIEW IF EXISTS master_foo;
                  DROP VIEW IF EXISTS bar1;
                  ...
    SQL

    execute sql
  end
end
```

**Hardware/software used:**

Machine where migrations are executed:

```
MacBookPro, Apple M1 Max, macOS Sonoma 14.2.1
ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [arm64-darwin21]
15.3 psql (PostgreSQL) 15.3 (Homebrew)
```

Production database server:

```
psql (14.9 (Homebrew), server 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg20.04+1))
```

Comment: @Alex Re: *"have you ever had an issue with it to warrant manual checks?"* I did not have an issue with `db/structure.sql` itself. But I have always done a manual check after `db:migrate`, before committing the resulting changes to `db/structure.sql`. This was to (a) ensure that the changes are exactly what I would predict from the migration code (create tables, add columns, etc), and (b) review the (changes in) SQL code after migration in the same way as I review the Rails migration code before migrating. It's just another code review layer, this time done in the SQL code, not Rails.

Comment: @Alex Once this manual inspection allowed us to catch a bug introduced by a dev on our team. The bug manifested in **huge** unrelated changes in `db/structure.sql`. We fixed the bug, and the `db/structure.sql` changes were restored to the small expected set of changes. At another time, we also got huge unrelated changes. I did a very cursory check of 2 tables whose sort order had changed. They looked OK, so I thought all was well. It turned out later that I (and 2 reviewers!) had missed a bug in our review. With so many changes, missing a small bug is not entirely unexpected.

Comment: @Alex I was under the impression that this is common practice: "[examine] the `diff` in GitHub and `git diff` output, which I use routinely to manually check `db/structure.sql` for sanity after the migration is executed." Maybe this assumption is wrong. For example, do you examine these changes manually after the migration?

Comment: @Alex Thank you in advance for your help! Perhaps it is worth turning your comment into an answer if you feel like it. It is definitely a valuable view of this issue, distinct from other answers. I appreciate it.

Comment: can't say i've had manually checking structure.sql as part of my routine. perhaps a different tool for the job is what you need https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/schema_diff.html

Comment: @Alex That's the one I am looking for! Huge thanks!!! If you make these into (even a very brief) answer, this would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: i've made my answer less short, in case that helps.

Comment: @Alex I really appreciate this addition to your (already very helpful) answer! I am now torn about how to properly assign the (rather small) 100 point bounty and "accepted answer" check between 3 (three!) helpful - and different - answers. All of them are great and all of them deserve bounty + accepted answer check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be caused due to different versions of the database engine you're using between different machines and/or configurations (like installed plugins). Example: After cloning the repo and recreating the database with the `structure.sql` from scratch, now some unexpected changes appears in this file: https://github.com/coopdevs/timeoverflow/pull/713/files.

Other possible cause is: Rails (Active Record) internal changes for better readability, consistency or any other reasons. Example: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44571.

Remember that differences in the order of tables or views in the `structure.sql` file (the same applies for the `schema.rb` approach) generally don't impact the functionality of your Rails application. But be careful, if you see other kind of changes, review them carefully (for example, in MySQL I've seen changes in the *collation* or the *charset*, which can cause actual weird problems in your app).

Regarding the "order", this can be forced by using the `:before` and `:after` options in your migrations. Example:

```
create_table :my_table, before: :my_other_table
```

Those options also work for columns:

```
add_column :my_table, :my_new_attribute, :integer, after: :my_other_column
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Could you please expand on this: "Rails (Active Record) internal changes for better readability or consistency." It is not clear to me how this works, because the rearranged items are in no obvious special order, and not any more readable or consistent than before.

Comment: Re: "Yes, this is mostly due to different versions of the database engine you're using between different machines and/or configurations." We have confirmed that very tiny (with some, but smaller amount of the  SQL code) migrations do not cause such unrelated changes. How is this consistent with the hypothesis that this is caused by db version differences? Also, what do you mean by this: "different versions of ... configurations". Where should I look for differences - which config files? Thank you again!

Comment: The idea about enforcing order is great! I have not seen it before, and will be sure to use it in the future code where it is needed.

Comment: Hey @TimurShtatland, just updated my answer with some examples. Hope they are useful!

Comment: Thank you so much! The examples are very useful indeed.

Comment: Thank you again for the answer! One question to clarify an important point: I was under the impression that this is common practice: *"[examine] the `diff` in GitHub and `git diff` output, which I use routinely to manually check `db/structure.sql` for sanity after the migration is executed."* Maybe this assumption is wrong. For example, do **you** examine these changes manually after the migration?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not related to different DB versions, it depends more on the order that different users run the migrations. If you have all your team blow away their DBs, and reload them from a common dump, then they'll all produce the same output... until someone runs a migration in a different order (which obviously will happen as soon as more than one user creates a new migration).

Unfortunately, there's no simple/nice way to resolve this.

#### Update replying to comments from OP:

> each running somewhat different postgresql versions on their laptops

Right, as I said, in my experience it has nothing to do with the PG version (maybe big version differences makes a difference, I never have big differences in my teams so can't comment).

> many years, many hundreds of migrations, and across a small team of developers [...] The changes in `db/structure.sql` were always consistent with the corresponding migrations

I've had the same experience, and then once things start changing/conflicting, it seems they never go back to the way they were. I've spent a lot of time (like a week of dedicated time) looking into it and never found any heuristic for why things started, nor how to return to the way things were. I **have** seen situations where only one member of a team experiences the "self-created migration triggers it in own structure", ie. other members can still create a migration, and the structure/schema is updated sensibly. But by this time it's often multiple members all experiencing the same thing, and obviously once one member experiences it then others will start seeing the conflicts/big changes when they pull from the shared repo.

Seems there's something internal in PG where after a certain level of schema complexity / db object size, it has to start storing new objects in some way that when they change the dump changes significantly. I've never seen it in a small DB.

#### Another Update

I was reminded of this gem https://github.com/jakeonrails/fix-db-schema-conflicts - I believe it requires you switch to using `schema.rb`, and when I tried it there were still some things it wasn't helping with, but they were quite specific, like triggers.

Comment: The developer who reported this (reproducible for them) issue did this: * Check out the most recent master version of our shared code repo from GitHub, * `dropdb test_foo`, * `createdb test_foo`, * Load `db.structure.sql` from the above shared repo (which reflects all the migrations in the repo so far), * Add the **new** migration file which should run alone, as it is the only migration that is not migrated yet, * Run this new, most recently added migration. --> And then they got these unexpected changes.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "until someone runs a migration in a different order (which obviously will happen as soon as more than one user creates a new migration)." Could you please expand a little on this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, we have never seen this exact issue before. We have multiple developers write and run migrations, that has never been a problem. We always run the migration, then commit the migration **and** the corresponding  change in `db.structure.sql` and push to the shared repo. In this case we confirmed that the single new migration ran and caused the changes, and no other migrations ran.

Comment: Right, any migration can change the order of the PG dump, and therefore your schema.rb or structure.sql file. Sorry, I had misunderstood the "changes" you were talking about as conflicts between different users, which also happens.

Comment: We routinely look at `git diff` output (or the `diff` on GitHub) after we run migrations `db/structure.sql`. We did this across many years, many hundreds of migrations, and across a small team of developers (each running somewhat different postgresql versions on their laptops). All this time, the output of `git diff` made sense. It was exactly as expected from the migrations' code: a few tables/views/matviews changed here, a few columns changed there. The changes in `db/structure.sql` were always consistent with the corresponding migrations. ...

Comment: ... The order of unrelated tables/views/matviews never changed. Until this migration now. Why did it change now, and how can I prevent this unpleasant change from happening in the future? Your answer implies that the behavior we have seen before is a lucky coincidence. And we should have expected such unrelated changes in order all that time. Finally, they happened, and it is not surprising in your experience. And there is little we can do about it. Do I understand your answer correctly? Thank you again for the clarification!

Comment: I'll add responses to my answer...

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. One question to clarify an important point: I was under the impression that this is common practice: *"[examine] the `diff` in GitHub and `git diff` output, which I use routinely to manually check `db/structure.sql` for sanity after the migration is executed."* Maybe this assumption is wrong. For example, do **you** examine these changes manually after the migration?

Comment: The diff, even with the superfluous reordering/etc, is still fairly easy to visually check the changes you've made. I personally don't do that, I rely on my tests and if it's something tricky I'll be checking the DB schema directly in `psql`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, it is very valuable info for me!

Comment: Just added another update to my answer of a gem workaround that I remembered.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update re `fix-db-schema-conflicts` gem!

Answer (score 2):

Sorting algorithm is quite complex and it is internal to `pg_dump`, and it seems to be done on a best [effort](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/a3a836fb5e51183eae624d43225279306c2285b8/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump_sort.c#L918) basis:
*https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump_sort.c*

There is really nothing you can do from rails side, other than maybe writing a script that would do an object-wise diff instead of a line-wise git diff. If you think there are unrelated changes that could be avoided, than it should just be a bug report for `pg_dump`.

There are other tools that can be used to diff your database changes for review process:
*https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/schema_diff.html*
*https://github.com/stripe/pg-schema-diff*

---

Here is my quick diff attempt:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def parse_blocks(filename)
  enum = File.open(filename).each
  blocks = []

  loop do
    line = enum.next
    next unless line.match?(/^--/)

    blocks << []
    loop do
      blocks.last << line unless line.match?(/^--|^$/)
      break if line.match?(/^$/) && enum.peek.match?(/^--/)

      line = enum.next
    end
  end

  blocks
end

before, after = ARGV

puts "+++"
added = parse_blocks(after) - parse_blocks(before)
puts added

puts

puts "---"
removed = parse_blocks(before) - parse_blocks(after)
puts removed
```

git would show resorted tables above CREATE VIEW:

```bash
$ ./pg_diff db_bak.sql db_bak2.sql
+++
CREATE VIEW public.bar AS
 SELECT products.name
   FROM public.products
UNION ALL
 SELECT properties.name
   FROM public.properties;
ALTER TABLE public.bar OWNER TO admin;

---
CREATE TABLE public.categories (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
    ancestry character varying,
    created_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE public.categories OWNER TO admin;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative comments and the answer, including the links and the code. I appreciate the `pg_dump_sort.c` pointer, and your sharing of your practice re object-wise vs. line-wise `git diff db/structure.sql`. This was not an obvious solution to me at all, but seems now like a very sensible path!